# Приоритет операторов в javascript

Tags: javascript

Какой оператор ! или > выполнится раньше (и почему?) в следующей строке:
    if (!$.inArray(x, xx) > -1) {
    ...
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

список операторов согласно их приоритету (от наивысшего к самому низкому).

> 1. ++, –, – (унарный), ~, !, typeof.
> 2. *, /, %.
> 3. +, -.
> 4. <<, >>, >>>.
> 5. > , >=, <, <=.
> 6. ==, !=, ===.
> 7. &.
> 8. ^.
> 9. |.
> 10. &&.
> 11. ||.
> 12. =, +=, –=, *=, /=, %=, &=, |=, ^=.

P.S. Используя скобки, можно изменить приоритеты! Выражение, заключенное в скобки, всегда вычисляется раньше других на том же уровне вложенности

Comment: и? т.е. согласно этой таблице сначала выполняется ! потом >? так? а то вопрос был немного другой

Comment: Добавлю, что 

    if (!$.inArray(x, xx) > -1) { code(); }

эквивалентно

    // if ([true or false] > -1) { code(); } -->
    // if ([0 or 1] > -1) { code(); } -->
    // if (true) { code(); } -->
    code();

Comment: Ну **&&** же...